# python database query using two scripts

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two scripts main.py and testscript.py. On main.py is the function to connect to my database and on testscript.py I will use as my query request and call this query to my database by using main.py. Adding to main.py

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
        q = "select domain_name from domains_domain limit 10"
        query(q)
```

and run script

> python main.py

working as is expected, but I don't know how to do this on testscript.py

Here is main.py

```
import MySQLdb
from localdb import *
import socket

host = socket.gethostname()
error_report = "Check if MySQL service is running and user name/password are correct" 

class WeekQuery:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def query(self):
        cursor = None
        results = None
        week_number = None
        #Connecting to production database
        if host == 'db01':
            try:
                db = MySQLdb.connect("db01", "myuser", "mypass", "mydb")
                cursor = db.cursor()
                cursor.callproc(self)
                results = cursor.fetchall()
                week_number = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
            except MySQLdb.Error, e:
                try:
                    print "%s \n MySQL Error [%d]: %s" % (error_report, e.args[0], e.args[1])
                except IndexError:
                    print "%s \n MySQL Error: %s " % (error_report, str(e))
        else:

            #local database rename localdb.py_example to localdb.py
            try:
                db = MySQLdb.connect(host=MYSQL_HOST, user=MYSQL_USER, passwd=MYSQL_PASSWD, db=MYSQL_DATABASE)
                cursor = db.cursor()
                cursor.execute(self)
                results = cursor.fetchall()
                week_number = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
            except MySQLdb.Error, e:
                try:
                    print "%s \n MySQL Error [%d]: %s" % (error_report, e.args[0], e.args[1])
                except IndexError:
                    print "%s \n MySQL Error: %s " % (error_report, str(e))

            #finally:
            #    cursor.close()
            #    db.close()
            print(results, week_number) #For debuging only
        return (results, week_number)
```

Here my testscript.py

```
from main import WeekQuery

def sample():
    q = "select domain_name from domains_domain limit 10"
    x = WeekQuery(q)
    for y in x.query():
        print(y)
```

Comment: What is the problem? Define default query in your WeekQuery class if you need it.

Comment: Problem is that python sampletest.py is returning a error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 11, in <module>
    sample()
  File "script.py", line 7, in sample
    for y in x.query():
  File "/home/robert/projects/python/scripts/example_tests/db_query_function/main.py", line 36, in query
    cursor.execute(self)`

Comment: is that all error text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need tom import host and error_report too from main. Is that your problem ?

Comment: No, no the problem that in samplescript.py I want put query and that query is used in main.py as 'self' and gives me results

Comment: Ah ok, so you have a problem with dealing with objects and fields. You could for example add a q field in your WeekQuery class, adding the corresponding parameter to the __init__ method and that should work

Comment: I have add `class WeekQuery:
    q = "select domain_name from domains_domain limit 10"
    def __init__(self, q):
        self.q = q`
but `python sampletest.py` gives me `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampletest.py", line 9, in <module>
    sample()
  File "sampletest.py", line 4, in sample
    x = WeekQuery(q)
NameError: global name 'q' is not defined`

Comment: It's fine, just leave q="select ..." outside where it was (in sample() function) not in WeekQuery. It's just the Field that has to be defined in the class not the value

Comment: Ok, q="select.." is in sample function now is comming new issue.
First part of log:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampletest.py", line 10, in <module>
    sample()
  File "sampletest.py", line 6, in sample
    for y in x.query():
  File "/home/robert/projects/python/scripts/example_tests/db_query_function/main.py", line 36, in query
    cursor.execute(self)`

Comment: And second part of log:
`File "/home/robert/projects/python/scripts/example_tests/db_query_function/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 198, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, TypeError, m)
  File "/home/robert/projects/python/scripts/example_tests/db_query_function/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not instance`

Comment: Also replace cursor.execute(self) by cursor.execute(q)

Comment: ok I fixed by `cursor.execute(self.q)` I very appreciate for your help, Thank you